# Heroku can't open file created in worker

Tags: php, heroku, worker

So my project has 2 dynos [web, worker] both in PHP.

In `worker` I created a file (ex: `/app/abc.txt`) after a long running process.

In `web` I allow user to download that file, but even though I provide the exact file name, the system could not open it (it said file not found).

`2017-04-02T03:38:29.606293+00:00 app[worker.1]: [2017-04-02 03:38:29] myapp.INFO: [start] confirmed existence of /app/abc.txt [] []`

I confirmed the existence of the file by using `file_exists` function which return TRUE. (I even try `file_get_contents` and able to get the content with no problem). But when I try to access it from `web`.

`2017-04-02T04:21:13.226793+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-04-02 04:21:13] myapp.INFO: [api.download] find not found /app/abc.txt [] []`

Do anyone has any idea why that is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't access file in one dyno from another dyno, because they are different instances of VMs. What you CAN do is use external storage such as S3.

Comment: Confirmed. I have to transfer files from worker dyno to web dyno in order to access them. Thanks.